# Dependency in pipeline

Tags: cpu, cpu-pipelines

**Assume the pipeline is initially empty and the processor is given 8 instructions to execute. However, the 4th instruction is an instruction whose operands depend on the result of the previous instruction. The remaining instructions are independent of each other. Given the instructions are not re-ordered, how long does it take to execute 8 such instructions with and without pipelining? What if the instructions can be reordered, how long does it take to execute those instructions with pipelining? Derive your solution by drawing the timing diagram of instructions passing through the pipeline stages.
Where the stages are:
Fetch: 2 ns, Decode: 4 ns, Execute: 4 ns, Write-back: 2 ns**
I searched but couldn’t understand it, according to the internet with pipelining 4 stages * max stage time = 16ns so it says the answer to the 2nd question is 16ns. But I don’t get it, in my opinion, each stage takes 4ns, 8 instructions + 1 due to dependency, $4 \times 9 = 36$ns. And also why isn’t the first question simply $8$ stage $\times 12$ns = $96$ns, can’t we ignore the dependency since there is no pipeline? Thanks

Comment: (Effective line breaks in markdown: append two blanks to preceding line.)

Comment: @greybeard so 4ns.10 ?

Comment: (Sorry, can't even suggest an edit for too many suggestions pending review.) I find your question hard to grasp without proper formatting. Don't use a *low dot* to represent multiplication. There is \* or &times;: ×.